# Connecting a Numpy-based application with a Django API

Tags: python, django, api, numpy, caching

I have 3 matrices stored in cache that are used in a calculation process. Overall, they have 50.000 lines and 500 columns.

Every time that I need to perform that calculation, I duplicate those 3 matrices, manipulate them, perform the calculation and delete them from the cache.

The calculation is triggered by a web service call and the result of the calculation feeds the web service output. The web service is managed by a Django application, while the matrices and the calculation are managed by a Numpy-based application.

My problem is related to performance. Every time that Django gets a web service call, it triggers the Numpy-based application that access the cache to duplicate the matrices. The problem is that accessing the cache and duplicating the matrices is taking 5 seconds. In my view, duplicating the matrices should be virtually instantaneous, so I assume the problem is related to accessing the cache.

I used the cache solution because it’s the only way that I found to keep the matrices permanent and not related to user sessions.

Generally speaking, I have two options to solve the problem:
1) improving the current solution to make the cache access and matrices duplication an instantaneous process;
2) moving to a distinct solution, but I don’t know which it could be.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

I hope the code below is helpful. The instruction that makes the process slow is the last one (cache.get("account"+id)

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def recommend(request):
    params = request.data
    try:        
        rec = Recomendation(params)
        logger.info(rec.time)
        response = rec.recomend()
        return Response(response,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(e,status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

class Recomendation():
    def __init__(self,data):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.account = tryAccount(data["AccountID"]) #return the matrix
        if self.account:
            self.store = self.account.getStore(data["StoreID"]) #Selects a store

            try:
                #Purchase parameters
                self.sellingHour = data["Time"]
                self.temperature = data["Temperature"]
                self.registeredItems = data["ItemsList"]
                self.weekDay = data["WeekDay"]
                self.weekDayWeight = data["WeekDayWeight"]
                self.monthWeek = data["MonthWeek"]
                self.monthWeekWeight = data["MonthWeekWeight"]
                self.BaseSup = data["TimeSuperiorPlateau"]
                self.BaseInf = data["TimeInferiorPlateau"]
                self.Height = data["TimeMinWeight"]
                self.environmentFilterOn = data["EnvironmentFilterOn"]
                self.sellingTemperature = data["Temperature"]
                self.tempBaseSup = data["TempSuperiorPlateau"]
                self.tempBaseInf = data["TempInferiorPlateau"]
                self.tempHeight = data["TempMinWeight"]
                self.rainy = data["Rainy"]
                self.rainyWeight = data["RainyWeight"]
                self.itensToRecommend = data["ItemsToRecommend"]
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            #Do code here
            self.utilityMatrix = np.asarray(self.store.utilityMatrix)
            self.productMatrix = np.asarray(self.store.productMatrix)
            self.contextMatrix = np.asarray(self.store.contextMatrix)

        else: 
        print(“error”)

    endtime = time.time()
        self.time = endtime - start_time

#another scope
def tryAccount(id):
    return cache.get("account"+id)
```

Comment: Could you give a minimal working example? It's quite hard to optimize your code without knowing what you did. I certainly don't get close to 5 sec for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

How about serializing your numpy arrays instead of storing them in the cache? [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is how you do that.

Of course a memory-based solution would be better, but with things of that size, reading from disk should be fast either way.

`np.load(filename)` will give you your matrices back.

#### UPDATE

I just realized something about Python that could fix your problem. When Python imports a file/library somewhere, it only really does it once, and then caches the loading somewhere. So you'll want to make a file that looks like this

```
print("loading matrices")
m1, m2, m3 = numpy.loads('./filename1.npy'), \
    numpy.loads('./filename2.npy'), numpy.loads('./filename3.npy')
print("matrices loaded")

def operation_one(inputs):
    m1_c, m2_c, m3_c = m1.copy(), m2.copy(), m3.copy()
    # Do the rest of your fist operation
```

Then, wherever you need to use this operation, just import the file. I believe that no matter how many times you import that file, it'll only load the matrices from disk once. And you can ensure that operation_one doesn't modify the original matrices.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm open to any efficient solution. As per my calculations, I need to be able to access all three matrices in less than 0.1 second (less than 0.05 seconds ideally). On top of that, in peak hours, I have around 80 web service calls per second, what will require the application to read the 3 matrices 80 times per second. Is the suggested process able to handle all those requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately, definitely not. 50000 lines * 500 columns is 25 million entries, which is at minimum 25 MB. You can read that from the disk in a tenth, but not 80 times (that's 2GB per second).

Comment: Edited question with alternative solution that (might) be fast enough. But if it's not, I think you're just out of luck as far as doing this on a single machine goes.

Comment: Another thing: what are you doing with those exactly? The answer to your question might just be smarter pre-computing (if there's something you can do once instead of for every request), or somehow thinning your data.

Comment: The solution is based on matrices manipulation and multiplication, so no pre-processing is applicable.

Comment: The reason why I’m using cache, is the fact that it was the only that I found to keep the matrices in memory permanently and indepently of Django sessions. Is there any way of keeping the matrices in the memory without using cache?

Comment: If it's taking that long, maybe it's just running out of memory. You're really asking a lot of your computer, I would try and do a rough estimate of how many floating point operations you're asking for at peak time. It could just be impossible. The cache should do it though. Another thing to consider, what do the inputs look like? If there is some repetition, you can cache input-ouput pairs so you don't have to re-compute when two people ask for the same thing. That can lower your computation big time.

Comment: The calculation problem is very dynamic, so caching input-output pairs won’t be effective. Leaving the peak time issue aside for a moment, my first problem is related to the cache access that takes 5 seconds in a controlled environment. That’s the problem that I need to solve now.

Comment: I need to find a way to store the matrices in the memory, make them available to Django in a way that it’s independent of web sessions, and make them available quickly. The only way I found to do that is through cache. Although the matrices are big, duplicating them in the memory should be a very quick process, however it’s taking 5 seconds, and I’m pretty sure the problem is related to accessing the cache and not duplicating the matrices. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking over your code, does the cache store a separate matrix for each accountId? That's what tryAccount seems to do. Does it have to? Does each user have their own matrix they need?

Comment: Yes. I have an array with multiple Accounts (each account represents a corporate entity not a user), where each Account has a group of Stores and each Store has its own three matrices.

Comment: What does getStore do exactly? Is it just a basic accessor method?

One of your problems might be that when you call tryAccount, if you're fetching all associated stores, you end up fetching all of the store's associated matrices at once. If an account has many stores this could be the bottleneck.